# How to display notification at a particular time

Tags: android

please tell what i can add to the below code to display notification at a particular time

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView wv1;
        Context context;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.YahooWhether);


            wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "here u go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            wv1.loadUrl("https://www.yahoo.com/news/weather/pakistan/sindh/karachi-2211096/");

            sendNotification();



        }
        public void sendNotification() {

    //Get an instance of NotificationManager//

            Notification.Builder mBuilder =
                    new Notification.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                            .setContentTitle("Whether Update")
                            .setContentText("Tomorrow's Forecast");


    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service//

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =

                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());

        }

    }
```

Ive displayed notification by default but not time specific. Please help. i cant get how to add alarmanager or whatever class that needs to be addded in order to display notification.

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-alarmmanager-tutorial.html 

this is the example of Alarm Manager. from here u can implement ur own logic & display notification when alarm trigger.

Comment: my only requirement is to display notfication at a particular time. so can i have something like setting a condition that a certain time is reached and if that the notification is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one `AlarmManager` class
It is not complicated, this is a reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html
this is a pratice:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
More or less your code i would write it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView wv1;
        Context context;
        AlarmManager alarmManager;
        Intent notificationAlert;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.YahooWhether);


            wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "here u go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            wv1.loadUrl("https://www.yahoo.com/news/weather/pakistan/sindh/karachi-2211096/");

            alarmManager = ( AlarmManager ) context.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ); //request alarm service
            notificationAlert = new Intent( context, sendNotification.class ); //intent to connection at broadcastReceiver class
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context, 0, notificationAlert, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ); //request broadcast in AlertNotification class
            try{
                alarmManager.setRepeating(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, //alarm time in system
                        0, //start milliseconds
                        1000, //difference time to go
                        pendingIntent
                );
            }
            catch( ParseException e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

I use `AlarmManager.setReapeating` To repeat the Alarm until you do `AlarmManager.cancel( pendingIntent );`
Otherwise you can use it `AlarmManager.set`

make new class notification:

```
public class sendNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ){

    Drawable icon = context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

    //Get an instance of NotificationManager//

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new Notification.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(icon)
                            .setContentTitle("Whether Update")
                            .setContentText("Tomorrow's Forecast");


    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service//

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =

                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());

    }

        }
```

Into `AndroidManifest.xml` add

```
<receiver android:name=".sendNotification"/>
```

in `application` tag

Let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: getting error on getSystemService also how can i set time on setrepeating. like a specific time

Comment: the code is incorrect. c is context. If this is the error, do not make a copy of my code, but try to study it. Now I fix this

Comment: i got the c thing, just the getSystemService error in the broadcastreceiver class

Comment: this error doesnt occur in the activity class but the broadcast receiver class

Comment: have you tried  `context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)`?

Comment: Please tell me what it did not go with `getSystemService` and what error you to with buider

Comment: i  had to delcare a non static context variable for the bulder its saying that: Builder (android.content.Context)       in Builder cannot be applied to         (com.example.inara,whetherapp.notify)

Comment: try `NotificationCompat.Buider`. Not all notification features are available for a particular version

Comment: actually i had to pass the context parameter to it. and it removed the error. now i have to add the notification activity to the manifest. how can i do tht? cz without that the application crashes

Comment: I had to post this too. Now I modify my answer.